# Why can't I delete on cascade ORM side?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When calling

```
$em->remove($news);
```

I got a constraint violation error.

I have 2 entities, news and image.

In `News` I have 3 references to `Image`, like this:

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
  */
  private $cover;

  /**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
  */
  private $img;

  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="news", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $gallery;
```

Inside `Image` I have just a reference to news, like this:

```
/**
    * @var News
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="gallery", cascade={"remove"})
    */
    private $news;
```

I know that I have a constrait running out there but shouldn't cascade={"remove"} ORM side be there for this reason?

What am I missing here? If i add

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
```

to the manyToOne relation, it just works fine. I would like to know if and how is it possible to have it ORM side.

Answer (score 0):

You `cascade={"remove"}` being set on `News` side, just like you did for `$gallery` association.

```
 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="news", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $gallery;
```

Do the same for other associations.

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $cover;

  /**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $img;

  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="news", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $gallery;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this was one shot I tried. I just retried it now to be sure and I can confirm you that if I remove the JoinColumn with onCascade and put cascade remove to other entities the constraint violation remains

Comment: Are you sure you're updating your db with {bin/app}/console doctrine:schema:update --force? not going to lie, I've argued with entity relationships for ages before remembering to run that

Comment: @JezEmery yes, sir. I've done the changes accordingly to this asnwer, updated db and tried once more. Unfortunately the result is the same. It doesn't wanna delete the parent entity while the constraint is up. I used a listener to set the relation to null before being capable to delete the images. But that's not ortodox